# How big is Gormenghast?

Tags: gormenghast, mervyn-peake

Gormenghast, the vast rambling castle-state that forms the setting for (the first two books of) Mervyn Peake's eponymous trilogy, is ***BIG***. But how big? Based on the evidence scattered here and there throughout the text, can we get any sort of idea or estimate of just how big this building complex is?

I seem to recall, during the floods in book 2, mention of a minor disused wing of the castle, many stories high and a mile long, being set aside for refugees while the lower floors of Gormenghast were flooded. This is what really brought home to me that it's bigger than any real building existing in the world, but how specific can we get?

Comment: Very  ***BIG***! Sorry, couldn't help myself ;)